# application that relies on .dll builds correctly, then can't find that DLL at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I have written an application in Visual Studio 2013 that relies on a DLL called WSTP32i1.dll. Both the dll and its associated .lib file are included in the project and it compiles and builds without error. However, when I run it, I get this:

[image]

Putting a copy of the DLL in the application folder doesn't help. When I check the Solution Explorer, the DLL appears to be marked "Does not participate in build," which seems wrong but I'm not sure what to change it to.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not participate in the build, little point in adding it to your project.  You need to copy it to the build directory, use a post-build event that uses XCOPY to copy it to $(OutputPath).  So after building it is present in the same directory as your EXE.  If you still have trouble then you forgot to copy another dependent DLL, diagnose with SysInternals' Process Monitor or contact Wolfram for support.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Explorer tree contains source files (cpp, h, rc etc.) used to build executables. Item Type property defines how this file will be processed. DLL is not a valid source file and IDE does not know how to process it. That is why it "Does not participate".

The standard (and the easest) way to link import library is to add reference to DLL project in `Common Properties / References` page of application project. By default, all DLL and EXE files of your solution are built in the same `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)` directory, so everything is ready to use without any adjustments and post-build events.

If your DLL is built in another solution, make sure that it is placed in the same folder as EXE file, or DLL's folder is specified in PATH environment variable.

Comment: I don't see Common Properties / References. I do see Common Properties / Dependencies, but there doesn't seem to be any way to add to it.

Comment: Select your project (not solution) in Solution Explorer, click Alt+Enter, find Common Properties / References.

Comment: Yeah, I get the dialog box, and it has a button "Add New Reference," but clicking on it brings up an "Add Reference" box that is completely unresponsive except for an "OK" and a "Cancel" button both of which just make the box go away.